# How to alter partition in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning, postgresql-11

Actually I am new to PostgreSQL. I want to alter existing partition to increase range value. For example I have below partition

**PQR_271 FOR VALUES FROM ('260000000') TO ('270000000')**

Here I want to extend the range to max value but I am not able to do the same.

I tried below solution

```
CREATE TABLE public.PQR_272 PARTITION OF public.stats_to_institution FOR VALUES FROM ('270000000') TO ('280000000');
ALTER TABLE public.PQR_272 OWNER to usr_replica;
```

Here I can increase the integer value but I cannot increase to maxvalue. Is there any solution to set range to maxvalue?

PostgreSQL version11

Comment: I have never done this, but looking [at the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) I would assume you need to detach the partition, then re-attach it with the new partition bounds

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it will delete the data too.

Comment: No, detaching a partition does not delete the data

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It did, I tried.

Comment: It works just fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c8d589d3019d39109d07fd3dede1cf59

Comment: Btw: why are you storing numbers as text?

Answer (score 11):

You can't alter the definition of a partition, but you can re-attach it with a different definition.

```
alter table stats_to_institution detach partition pqr_272;
alter table stats_to_institution attach partition pqr_272 
  for values FROM ('270000000') TO ('300000000'); --<< new upper bound
```

Obviously the data in that partition won't be visible in the main table between the detach and attach operation, but the data is still there.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c8d589d3019d39109d07fd3dede1cf59)

Comment: thats for the solution. Even this query worked for me. 
 `CREATE TABLE others PARTITION OF pqr FOR VALUES FROM ('280000000') TO (MAXVALUE);`